# Buildling subprojects error: Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found

Tags: android, gradle

I am getting this error "Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found." when trying to build my library.  This is with gradle 2.4.

My package structure is as follows:

/build/{branch}/ <-- Contains build scripts, version info, config info, packaging config

/library/{branch} <-- Library source code

/app/{branch} <-- Application source code

If I run the build task from the library project it works, but when I try and run it from the build folder as a subproject task I get the following error:

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':samplelibrary'.

  > Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found.

I have included the project path in settings.gradle and my build.gradle looks like this:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    evaluationDependsOnChildren()

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}

task buildlib dependsOn project(':samplelibrary').build{
    println 'Built project'
}
```

Then I run "gradle buildlib" and get 
"* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':samplelibrary'.

> Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found."

What do I need to do to resolve this build error?

Comment: "my build.gradle looks like this" -- where is this `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Within the build folder.  See the package structure in the post.  The build folder contains the build scripts to build the library, the application, docs, and then package them together for release.  The build.gradle in build folder should trigger the build tasks contained in the library and application folders.

Comment: Normally, in a Gradle for Android project, `build/` is output, not input. You might wish to experiment with a more traditional setup, get that working, then try to migrate to your desired structure.

Comment: The project was migrated from existing eclipse projects built with ant.  I am trying to follow the existing folder structure.  Gradle should be able to handle triggering sub-project tasks from different folder.  i just can figure out why it cannot find the plugins.